# What should I use? index.php, front-page.php and home.php

Tags: theme-development

I'm building a WordPress theme but I'm bit confused. I don't know what to use. There is `home.php`, `front-page.php` or `index.php`. When I started building the WordPress theme I started with `index.php` and gave it this code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

after that I found that there is that 3 pages `index.php`, `front-page.php` and `home.php`. So I realised that I need front-page.php, from what I heard it loads first so I will use it for front page which will have news slideshow and etc. Well now here is the question, what for is `index.php` or `home.php`? Do I really need these two files? And can I use `index.php` as front-page? Do I really need `front-page.php`? Can't I just use `index.php`?

Thank you.

Comment: Read http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy. That should answer all these questions.

Answer (score 3):

The codex on the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy):

1. WordPress first determines whether it has a static front page. If a static front page has been set, then WordPress loads that page according to the page template hierarchy.
2. If a static front page has not been set, then WordPress looks for a template file called home.php and uses it to generate the requested page.
3. If home.php is missing, WordPress looks for a file called index.php in the active theme's directory, and uses that template to generate the page.

[image]